# Mac OS X will not connect to a specific IP only

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

Running OS X 10.6.8 and can not connect to a specific website through my router. I know the website is working since its mine. 
I don't have a problem with any other IP just this one.

Factory rebooted my Router, contacted my provider they do not have a problem to connect. When I use my mobile phone connection I connect with no problem.

Tried to flush DNS with terminal, nothing works. Thx for your help.

Comment: Is it a problem with the domain, or the IP? Please clarify.

Comment: try pinging it.

Comment: There is no problem with the domain or the ip. Tried to ping it I get a the IP back but get Request timeout for icmp_seq.

Comment: Is this a site hosted on the same LAN as the machine that can't reach it? And is the site hosted on a machine with a private IP and reachable over the Internet through port forwarding. If so, it's common to only be able to reach it from the LAN on its private IP address. Not all routers support hairpain NAT (port forwarding from an inside machine to an inside machine).

Comment: No it is a public IP 184.154.196.139 and anyone can connect to it except me.

Comment: tried traceroute and it gets stuck somewhere on the way. thx for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

184.154.196.139 doesn't appear to be running a web server on port 80. It's specifically refusing connections to that port. Are you sure you don't mean 184.154.196.138? The DNS seems inconsistent:

```
139.196.154.184.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer web15.brainhost.com.
web15.brainhost.com.    14323   IN      A       184.154.196.138
```

Comment: Thx for the help, found out that somebody messed with the DNS entry, changed it back and it should work